# Regenerating iOS certificate for a free account

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I know that, you can now run your iOS app on any device with the advent of Xcode 7 and above, without having a Paid Developer Membership account. Unfortunately my free account's certificate **got revoked** and hence while running any application on my device I get this error -

> A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.

This is quite obvious as any provisioning profile containing my free certificate will now be invalid.

My question is how do i solve this issue and still run my app on a device without buying a Paid membership?

P.S - As it is a free account, I am not able to see Certificates, Provisioning Profile button on my apple developer homepage. (I guess you already know that)

Comment: Delete the certificate from the keychain and try again? Make a new free account?

Comment: @matt - I deleted the certificate from the keychain but the same error. Yes i know making a new free account might help but i am finding for a better solution so that i can use the same email-id. Otherwise i will have to create a new email-id just for this sake.